# How do I programatically change the default value of, or remove from default view, title column using javascript?

Tags: 2010, list, javascript, client-object-model

Using the JSOM in SharePoint 2010, if I am creating lists programmatically using something like:

```
this.myField= oList.get_fields().addFieldAsXml('<Field DisplayName=\'Key\' Type=\'Text\' />', true, SP.AddFieldOptions.defaultValue);   
    var fieldObj = clientContext.castTo(myField,SP.FieldNumber);
    fieldObj.set_defaultValue('-');
    fieldObj.update();
    clientContext.load(myField);
```

and something list this for updating the list...

```
this.oList = oWebsite.get_lists().add(listCreationInfo);
oList.set_description('New Announcements List');
oList.update();
clientContext.load(oList);
```

but what if I want to access like the title column that already gets created and change its default value to "..." and remove it from the default view. Am I able to do that?

EDIT: this seems to be right along the lines of where I am trying to get however I can't seem to get at the ViewFields of the CAML, only the Query portion.

```
var listCollection = web.get_lists();
var list = listCollection.getByTitle("ExampleList");
var viewCollection = list.get_views();
var view = viewCollection.getByTitle("All Items");

var query = '<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\'Title\' Ascending=\'False\' /></OrderBy>';
//instead of set_viewQuery I would like to get at the ViewFields...is that possible?
view.set_viewQuery(query);
view.update();
```

Tried this, but I can't get it to change the list's default All Items View, it seems to only remove it from the forms for me??

```
   var cxt = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var oWebsite = cxt.get_web();
        this.oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle('ExampleList);
        fieldCollection = oList.get_fields();
        this.oneField = fieldCollection.getByInternalNameOrTitle("Title");
        this.oneField.set_hidden(true);
        this.oneField.set_required(false);
        this.oneField.update();
        cxt.load(this.fieldCollection);
        cxt.load(this.oneField);
        cxt.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onUpdatedTitleFieldSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

I also noticed that if I use the above, the All Items view still shows Title, but it is removed from the form, and if I browse through the web UI to list settings, the column does not appear in the columns list....weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### How to remove field from List View via CSOM (JavaScript)

```
function DeleteFieldFromListView(url,listTitle,fieldName,OnSuccess,OnError) {

    var context = new SP.ClientContext(url);
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var view = list.get_defaultView();
    var viewFields = view.get_viewFields();
    context.load(viewFields);

    context.executeQueryAsync(function(sender,args){
        viewFields.remove(fieldName);
        view.update(); 
        context.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnError);

    },OnError);        
}
```

Example: remove Title column from default view in List titled `Grammy Awards`

```
DeleteFieldFromListView('https://contoso.sharepoint.com/',
'Grammy Awards',
'LinkTitle',
function(){
    console.log('Field has been deleted from View')
},
function(sender,args){
    console.log('Error occured:' + args.get_message());
}
);
```

> LinkTitle corresponds to Title column

Comment: awesome! I had to change it slightly from get_defaultView to viewCollection.getByTitle("All Items") in order to get it to work for me. Thanks very much...appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
        fieldCollection = oList.get_fields();
        this.oneField = fieldCollection.getByInternalNameOrTitle("Title");
       this.oneField.set_hidden ();

        this.oneField.update();

        clientContext.load(this.fieldCollection);
        clientContext.load(this.oneField);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));
```

Refer the following for more clarity

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245336.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246815.aspx

Comment: thanks but I believe that set_hidden() only removes the field from the form display and I am trying to affect the "All Items" default view that gets created. the above does remove it from the forms (which is cool I didn't know about this) but I still can't get it removed from the default view.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245336.aspx states that the field is hidden in list views and list forms.

Comment: hmmm...well it must be something I am doing wrong then. will post update to my question to show ya what I got. thanks for the help.